# Fading in the Angular Router Outlet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Trying to fade in the Angular Router Outlet.

This is the CSS Code (app-component.css).

```
router-outlet + * {
  display: block;
  animation: fade 1s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

[And this is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lobhre?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css).  The router outlet content is not being faded in.  Any ideas?

Comment: `router-outlet + *` it picks all the sibling items of router-outlet.

Comment: [Use Angular's recommendation](https://angular.io/guide/route-animations) instead

Comment: As @MGX said, you should use the [Anular build in transitions](https://angular.io/guide/route-animations) for this. [Here](https://zerotomastery.io/blog/angular-animations-and-examples/) is a nice article on how to apply a fade transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read more about component styling in Angular [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles).

Following is the compilation of your `app.component.css` CSS:

[image]

But, sibling for `router-outlet` will be always a different component injected by `RouterModule`.

In order to solve the issue, there are two solutions.

1. Move `router-outlet + *` animation css to `styles.css` file.
2. Add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in `app.component.ts` file as shown below.

[image]

Comment: OH Cool.  I switched off the view encapsulation and now it works.  Here's the forked demo.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r6gxyo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts